# What is a "double star-product"

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-algebra

Michel Van den Bergh introduced the notion of a [double Poisson algebra](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410528). The definition is cooked up such that the representation varieties of such an algebra are Poisson varieties.

Is there a notion of "quantization", or "double star-product" for double Poisson algebras, so that it would induce genuine star-products quantizing the above mentioned Poisson varieties ?

---

EDIT: being more precise, if an associative algebra $A$ is equipped with a double Poisson structure, then for any $n\geq0$ the affine variety $Rep_n(A)$ of $n$-dimensional representations of $A$ is naturally equipped with a (algebraic) Poisson structure. 
**Remark:** the symplectic version of this story goes back to [Crawley-Boevey, Etingof and Ginzburg](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AG/0502301), who studied  representation of quivers using non-commutative symplectic geometry). 
Now my question is following:

> What kind of algebraic structure on an
>   algebra $A$ ensures that one will get
>   star-products on $Rep_n(A)$. Here by a
>   star-product on an affine variety $X$
>   I improperly mean a formal
>   one-parameter deformation of its
>   function ring $\mathcal O_X$.